# Filter PHAssetCollections within radius of CLLocationCoordinate2d

Tags: ios, nspredicate, core-location, photokit, ckquery

I'm using the Photos framework (aka `PhotoKit`). In my app I need to gather Moments (which are of type `PHAssetCollection`). `PHAssetCollection` has a property of `CLLocation *approximateLocation`.

However I cannot get the `NSPredicate` to work when I retrieve the Moments from PhotoKit.

```
-(void)getMomentsNearCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate completionBlock:(PKAssetManagerArrayBlock)completionBlock{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        PHFetchOptions *options = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
        options.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"approximateLocation.coordinate.latitude < 37.0"];

        self.moments = [PHAssetCollection fetchMomentsWithOptions:options];

        // Convert PHCollection into NSArray
        NSMutableArray *momentsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:self.moments.count];
        [self.moments enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PHAssetCollection *moment, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            [momentsArray addObject:moment];
        }];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            completionBlock([NSArray arrayWithArray:momentsArray]);
        });
    });
}
```

The debugger will stop on

```
self.moments = [PHAssetCollection fetchMomentsWithOptions:options];
```

with the error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported predicate in fetch
>   options: approximateLocation.coordinate.latitude < 37'

This seems strange since I can use `NSPredicate` to filter by `startDate` or `endDate`.

Anyhow, next I thought I'd try the `NSPredicate` with block:

```
-(void)getMomentsNearCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate completionBlock:(PKAssetManagerArrayBlock)completionBlock{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        PHFetchOptions *options = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
        options.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
            // Logic goes here
            return YES;
        }];

        self.moments = [PHAssetCollection fetchMomentsWithOptions:options];

        // Convert PHCollection into NSArray
        NSMutableArray *momentsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:self.moments.count];
        [self.moments enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PHAssetCollection *moment, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            [momentsArray addObject:moment];
        }];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            completionBlock([NSArray arrayWithArray:momentsArray]);
        });
    });
}
```

Again the debugger stops at

```
self.moments = [PHAssetCollection fetchMomentsWithOptions:options];
```

with a different error message:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported predicate in fetch
>   options: BLOCKPREDICATE(0x27d338)'

Finally I remembered reading in [CloudKit documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKQuery_class/index.html) that they added a new support for filtering by distance. However this is for `CKQuery`, not `NSPredicate`. I decided to give it a try anyhow. I use my coordinate to make a `CLLocation` then call:

```
-(void)getMomentsNearLocation:(CLLocation*)location completionBlock:(PKAssetManagerArrayBlock)completionBlock{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        PHFetchOptions *options = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
        options.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"distanceToLocation:fromLocation:(%K,%@) < %f",
                             location,
                             2.0];

        self.moments = [PHAssetCollection fetchMomentsWithOptions:options];

        // Convert PHCollection into NSArray
        NSMutableArray *momentsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:self.moments.count];
        [self.moments enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PHAssetCollection *moment, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            [momentsArray addObject:moment];
        }];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            completionBlock([NSArray arrayWithArray:momentsArray]);
        });
    });
}
```

**You guessed it. Error:**

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CLLocation rangeOfString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x19e3e350'
```

In the mean time I'll just iterate through the list of `PHAssetCollections` and manually calculate if it's near the `CLLocation`. This will be far less efficient.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Comment: No. I haven't messed with the code much since the original post. Please post back if you get it working. Maybe it works in iOS 10?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at Table 1 of the PHFetchOptions documentation, you will see that you can only use the following keys for predicate filtering of PHAssetCollections:

```
SELF
localIdentifier
localizedTitle (or title)
startDate
endDate
estimatedAssetCount
```

if you want to filter a PHCollection (as opposed to an PHAssetCollection), then you are limited to the following keys:

```
SELF
localIdentifier
localizedTitle (or title)
startDate
endDate
```

Nothing resembling "approximateLocation" is a support key. **But wait!**  The localizedTitle is generally a place name. Have not seen it otherwise. So, you might be able to get assets by predicate filtering moment collections